# Share Apps Script Add-on outside domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

Is there a way to share a Google Apps Scripts add-on (for Google Sheets) with free gmails / outside the domain it was built for ?
 In our company everyone has domain emails but sometimes I would like to allow collaborators to use our add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is to [publish it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish). If you don't want to make it public you could make it unlisted or private, shared with a Google Group.

Comment: The only workaround would be to make the collaborators [install an unpublished add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on), but in this case you would need to share your code with them.